# How to encrypt txt with pgp?

Tags: java, spring-boot, pgp

I have a simple txt and I want to encrypt it with pgp,
I am currently using spring boot
I show you the txt

```
 List<String> info= new ArrayList<>();
       info.add("hello world");



    public List<String>  txt(List<String>  data) throws IOException {
        File nameFile = new File("test.txt");
        FileWriter save = new FileWriter("C:\\Downloads\\" +nameFile);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(save);
        for (String i: data){
            writer.println(i);
        }
        writer.close();
        return data;
    }
```

**how to encrypt with spring boot using pgp**

Comment: PGP is an external utility designed primarily for email encryption.  It is not an encryption algorithm.  And I am not sure it is readily available for Windows platforms.  Are you sure that you are asking the right question here?

Comment: You might be able to [do it](https://itecnote.com/tecnote/java-getting-gpg-decryption-to-work-in-java-bouncy-castle/)